# How to find the requested export inside module?

Tags: javascript

I'm struggling to get this to work and have a reviewed a number of previously asked questions on this topic but can't seem to resolve it

error: Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './filter.js' does not provide an export named 'filterFetchedArticles'

JS files (above closing body tag)

```
<script type="module" src="assets/js/filter.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="assets/js/news.js"></script>
```

filter.js

```
export function filterFetchedArticles() {
  // stuff
}
```

news.js

```
import { filterFetchedArticles } from "./filter.js";
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: have you read how to use [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) and [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Comment: I have yes, is there something you're getting at?

Comment: No, just wondering if you did - the code looks like it should work (it does when I reproduce it) - I mentioned it because you don't need to have `<script type="module" src="assets/js/filter.js"></script>` since `import` will read it - no other errors in the console?

Comment: No other errors! So confusing. Thanks for testing that

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the structure and names match correctly:

Project Folder

- filter.js
- index.js
- index.html
- style.css

filter.js

```
export function filterFetchedArticles() {
  return 'test';
}
```

index.js

```
import './style.css';
import { filterFetchedArticles } from './filter.js'


const appDiv = document.getElementById('app');
let filter = filterFetchedArticles();

appDiv.innerHTML = `<h1>JS Starter: ${ filter }</h1>`;
```

See demo [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-tgfpdm?file=index.js)